# Adding System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#

I am trying to add System.Security.Cryptography to a Visual Studio 2017 project. It is a Windows Form project.

My solution has 2 projects. I am trying to add System.Security.Cryptography to one project but I cannot find it in the reference manager.

I right click the project > Add > Reference. Then I go to COM > Type Libraries. But I cannot find it there.

Under dependencies I can see that I am using NETStandard.Library. Do I need a different library for System.Security.Cryptography? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: thats not a com reference. what type of library are you adding it to? .net standard?

Comment: @DanielA.White the dependencies says NETStandard.Library so I guess its a .net standard library.

Edit: the reference manager says: targetting NETStandard 1.6

Comment: The `Security.Cryptography` **nuget package** (not the namespace) is Microsoft's crypto utility library on NuGet, available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Security.Cryptography/ it does not have `System.` in the name. Otherwise, in .NET Framework (not .NET Standard or .NET Core), the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace is included in `mscorlib.dll` and `System.Core.dll` (both are default references). For .NET Core and .NET Standard it's in `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll`. But you should reference these assemblies via NuGet packages rather than as assembly references.

Comment: If your project is a WinForms project in VS2017 then you're certainly using .NET Framework, nor .NET Standard or .NET Core (you need VS2019 to use WinForms with .NET Core 3)

Comment: @Dai If I check Project > Manage NuGet Packages I can see that NetStandard.Library 1.6.1 is installed. If I check the dependencies there I can see that System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates (>= 4.3.0) is included under .NETStandard Version=v1.3.

I should be able to add System.Security.Cryptography then, right?

Comment: Figured it out. When I added a new project to the solution I chose Class Library (.Net Standard) instead of Class Library (.Net Framework 4.6.1).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add system.security.dll to my project by installing System.Security.Cryptography.protecteddata via nuget package manager in my visual studio, it also add system.security.cryptography to it